# PHP string compare (if) does not work

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I was writing in PHP and making so the page was declared by get method. For an example if it were `index.php?page=home` it would take home and compare to other strings and... ya include the home BUT the compression in the if statement dosnt work... I have also write that if get `method == start` then dont show the side news but it still showed it!

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'start'){
    $adbool = false;
}else{
    include('inc/main.php');
}
```

And here is the if statement for deleting side news:

```
if(isset($adbool) && !$adbool == false){
    include('inc/ad.php');
}
```

Comment: When is the include of the side news allowed? When $adbool is true or false?

Comment: Use `var_dump($_GET['page'])` to display its actual value. BTW, replace `if(isset($adbool) && !$adbool == false){` with `if(isset($adbool) && $adbool){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
if(isset($adbool) && $adbool){
    include('inc/ad.php');
}
```

this will check if `$adbool` is set, and if it's set to true.

Answer (score 1):

and remember this `!$adbool == false` is not equal to this `$adbool != false`

You better understand this part as well `!$adbool == false;`
 `!$adbool` means that `$adbool` is equal to false;

so `!$adbool == false;` means if `false=false` hence this condition always set to to true.

Thats why your logic is failing
Change this

```
if(isset($adbool) && !$adbool == false){
    include('inc/ad.php');
}
```

To this

```
if($adbool == TRUE){//simply check weather its set to to true or not
    include('inc/ad.php');
}
```